# Class does not exist by migrate the cacheManager to constructor injection

Tags: caching, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I have a problem with my cacheManager instance migration into TYPO3 10. According to the TYPO3 10 documentation, the cache should be injected via the constructor instead of an instance of "cacheManager".
I followed the documentation, the yaml config is also correct and I get an error message in the frontend.

`"Class TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\Frontend does not exist. Reflection failed."`

As far as I know, this class does not exist at all.
Is there a solution for this error?

*EXT:my_ext/Configuration/Services.yaml*

```yaml
services:
  cache.my_ext:
    class: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\FrontendInterface
    factory: ['@TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager', 'getCache']
    arguments: ['my_ext']
  MyVendor\MyExt\Connection\Http:
    arguments:
      $cache: '@cache.my_ext'
```

*EXT:my_ext/Classes/Connection/Http.php*

```php
    /**
     * @var FrontendInterface
     */
    private $cache;
    public function __construct(FrontendInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
    public function initializeObject() {
        $className = explode('\\', get_class($this));
        $this->extensionKey = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::camelCaseToLowerCaseUnderscored($className[1]);
    }
    public function getDataFromUrl($url, $cachingTags = array()) {
        $cacheIdentifier = sha1($url);
        $remoteData = $this->getUrl($url . "&" . time());
        if (($this->cache->get($cacheIdentifier)) === false) {
            $this->cache->set($cacheIdentifier, $remoteData, $cachingTags,36000);
        }
        return $remoteData;
    }
```

I followed the documentation here:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Developer/Index.html

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information? Which documentation? What have you configured in your yaml file? 
Guessing what's wrong is hard, if you already know, that you did all corresponding to the docs and all configuration is correct. If this would be, there shouldn't be an error ;-)

Comment: I ran into the same issue and looked into it, as to where this `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\Frontend` class came from.

In `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container->getImplementationClassName` the class `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\FrontendInterface` gets its Interface at the end of the classname stripped. Thus it becomes `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\Frontend`...

But it shouldn't even load the Interface in the first place, but the designated cache as configured...
I haven't got this to work either. What are we missing? Did you have any progress yet?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that in docs there were missing service default configs.

Following is the minimal configuration for me that worked.

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  Mohsin\HeadlessProducts\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
  cache.headless_products:
    class: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\FrontendInterface
    factory: ['@TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager', 'getCache']
    arguments: ['headless_products']
  Mohsin\HeadlessProducts\Utility\ProductsUtility:
    arguments:
      $cache: '@cache.headless_products'
```

Also, it's important to remove the cache from the install tool or CLI otherwise your changes will not reflect if you remove it from the backend only.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
Content of the `Services.yaml` file

```yaml
services:   _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  WimRoukema\WrCollection\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'

  cache.wr_collection:
    class: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\FrontendInterface
    factory: ['@TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager', 'getCache']
    arguments: ['wr_collection']

  WimRoukema\WrCollection\Controller\IndexController:
    public: true
    arguments:
      - '@cache.wr_collection'
```

Comment: Eap! Be careful. You didn't format your code—which is especially important when you're pasting the contents of a YAML file, since the indentation is so critical. I've updated your answer, but please review to understand how to format your own posts in the future. Also, when contributing an answer, be sure to look at how it's formatted before posting, and revise if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was not to use different keys in *localconf.php*.
According to named documentation you should use *myext_mycache* and *my_cache* in different places. When I used only *my_cache* it worked.

Answer (score 0):

just run clear cache and

```
composer dumpautoload
```